# Ext.JS: Reference model in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs, ext.net

Suppose I have a controller that returns a partial view:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult MyPartialView(int id)
    {
        var model = _myFactory.GetResult(id);
        return new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
        {
            RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
            ContainerId = "ContainingPanel",
            WrapByScriptTag = false,
            Model = model
        };
    }

    public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult Update(MyModel)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

and the model is defined like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public SomeEnum SomeEnum { get; set; }
    /// Other property definitions
}
```

and all this goes to a view:

```
@model MyModel
@{
    var x = Html.X();
}

@(x.FormPanel()
    .ID(string.Format("Details_{0}_", Model.Id))
    .Items(
        x.Button()
            .Text("Update")
            .Listeners(ls =>
            {
                ls.Click.Handler = string.Format("MyJS.onUpdateBtnClick('{0}', {1});", 
                    Url.Action("Update", "My"));
            })
        )
    )
```

with JavaScript that looks like this:

```
onUpdateBtnClick: function (url) {
    model = // code to get the model
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

My question is, what do I need to do to get the data in `MyModel` from `MyView`? I've heard tell of a function called `getViewModel` but I haven't been able to get that to work thus far (I've only ever seen `null` returned). Any help would be appreciated.